# MySQL DELETE 100x slower than SELECT

Tags: mysql, database, database-performance

I have a MyISAM table with ~5m row (~2.5GB) and I'm finding that delete operations are *very* slow. For example:

```
mysql> select * from twitter_tweets where parent_type='search' and parent_id=4;
...
661372 rows in set (5.35 sec)
mysql> delete from twitter_tweets where parent_type='search' and parent_id=4;
Query OK, 661372 rows affected (7 min 38.19 sec)
```

There is a compound (unique) index over parent_type, parent_id and tweet_id (in that order) and the explain plan of the select uses this index. It is worth noting, also, that parent_type only has two possible values and parent_id has about 100.

Is it normal to take this long? If not, what could be done to speed things up?

Comment: what kind of system are you running this on? Is anything else accessing the database at this time?

Comment: Have you tried to disable indexes before you execute the delete query and enable them afterwards? (`ALTER TABLE tbl_name [DISABLE|ENABLE] KEYS`)

Comment: If there is concurrent access...might be a locking issue...and therefore this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028465/innodb-row-level-locking-performance-how-many-rows

Comment: Isn't there an option to store `parent_type` as `UNSIGNED INT`, fk to another (e.g. `types`) table, instead of `(VAR)CHAR`? Numbers are indexed and retrieved much faster.

Comment: Disable keys, delete then enable keys is the answer! Thanks @crozin